# How to convert json to dart when json is a list of arrays?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Trying to use JSON_ANNOTATION but the json contains an array or arrays. Not sure how to convert path to Paths object that has multiple path objects.

Something like this maybe, but this isn't two levels deep?

```
{
  "paths":"$[]path"
}
```

JSON:

```
  "path": [

    [

      -97.76488387025893,
      30.39184803608805
    ],
    [

      -99.76488387025893,
      31.39184803608805
    ],
   .....
  ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily convert your json data to dart class with converters.

There are some tools on the web for that :

- [Json2Dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)
- [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/)

After, you just have to call the `fromJson()` method of the generated class to get your datas on it.